# Dynamic insert directive to template angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have question, is possible to: dynamic insert directive to template e.g.:

```
<div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="r in result">

  <span {{r.directive}}></span> //when restrict:"E", r.directive is directive name

</div>
```

OR

```
<div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="r in result">

    <span class="{{r.directive}}"></span> //when restrict:"C"

    </div>
```

Comment: what will be achieved by adding directive in that way?

Comment: I was wondering which way is good:
When I create one directive which have big functionality or I split functionality to separately directives.  In loop directive is change, once time will be text input another will be datapicker or other form element.

Comment: if you know you have `restrict` directive with `AE`, while using that directive on HTML you are going to use it as `attribute` or `element`, why you are creating confusion? I don't understand that..